# How to dynamically set button tooltip, text and icon simultaneously?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a button on a module pool screen. I need to change the icon, tooltip and text dynamically based on logic/a condition. I can successfully change the icon and text but am unable to change all three things (icon, text and tooltip) together.

Sample PBO code:

```
Data but(30) type c." here but is the name of button in screen.
write 'icon xxx' as ICON to but.
Concatenate but 'click here' into but separated by space.
```

It does not set the value of the tooltip, which should show "Please Click here to proceed". How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you define all the buttons, and dynamically hide the buttons you don't need?

Answer (score 1):

Use **ICON_CREATE** FM instead.

Here is the sample how to change all three attributes on-the-fly:

```
PARAMETERS: p_icon  TYPE icon_d MATCHCODE OBJECT h_icon,
            p_text  TYPE string,
            p_toolt TYPE string.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 500.
SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 49(30) but USER-COMMAND ret.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 500.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'ONLI'.
       CALL FUNCTION 'ICON_CREATE'
        EXPORTING
          name       = p_icon
          text       = p_text
          info       = p_toolt
          add_stdinf = 'X'
        IMPORTING
          result     = but.
      CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 500.
    WHEN 'RET'.
      LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
    WHEN OTHERS.
  ENDCASE.
```